# Como ler dados de arquivos txt usando Java?

Tags: java, arquivo

Existe algum mecanismo que permita armazenar em uma LinkedList os dados de um arquivo `.txt`? Por exemplo, como faria com que essa lista tivesse como elementos as Strings "Caio", "Pedro" e "Luiza"?

```
import java.io.*;

public class teste {
    public static void main ( String args [] ) throws IOException {
        LinkedList<String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>(); /*lista de Strings*/

        File arquivo = new File("C:\\NetBeans\\teste.txt");
        arquivo.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write("Caio Pedro Luiza");
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é realmente sua dúvida? ler o arquivo .txt e depois armazenar na Linked?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo

Comment: Já tem alguma feita? fica mais fácil para te orientar

Comment: pronto, editei a minha pergunta

Comment: Esses nomes estão separados por Virgula, espaço ou estão em linhas diferentes?

Comment: Estão separados por espaço

Comment: Removi a tag [linkedlist],pois a meu ver o seu problema não se trata de processamento de listas ligadas, você apenas está colocando as strings dentro de uma lista (que nem mesmo precisava ser uma lista ligada).

Comment: te recomendo dar uma lida nessa pagina aqui:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma alternativa, é utilizar a [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) disponibilizada na [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
(...)

// é fundamental definir o charset do arquivo
String conteudo = FileUtils.readFileToString("E:\\teste.txt", "UTF-8");
List<String> listaNomes = Arrays.asList(conteudo.split(" "));
System.out.println("Conteudo lista" + listaNomes);
```

Se for possível, separe os nomes no arquivo por linha ao invés de espaço (daí dá pra usar nomes completos). Ficaria assim:

```
List<String> listaNomes = FileUtils.readLines("E:\\teste.txt", "UTF-8");
System.out.println("Conteudo lista" + listaNomes);
```

A não ser que você tenha alguma restrição em adicionar dependências no seu projeto.

Answer (score 6):

**poirot**, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Testes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File arquivo = new File("E:\\teste.txt");
        arquivo.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write("Caio Pedro Luiza");
        bw.close();
        fw.close();

        LinkedList<String> listaNomes = new LinkedList<String>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("E:\\teste.txt"));

        while (in.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            String array[] = line.split(" ");

            for (String i : array) 
            {
                listaNomes.add(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Conteudo lista" + listaNomes);
        }

    }

}
```

Saida:

> Conteudo lista[Caio, Pedro, Luiza]

**Nota**: Não precisar ser um `LinkedList`, poderia ser qualquer outro tipo de `lista` até mesmo um `array` comum.

Comment: entendi! valeu, cara