# Como Obter dados de uma arquivo de text com java?

Tags: java, text

tenho um arquivo de texto com alguns dados na seguinte notação
[[name: Ricardo]]
e preciso de uma função que identifique esta marcação no meio do arquivo, e me retorne a string com o nome em questão.
Estive tentado o faze-lo com um laço for correndo pelo arquivo em busca dos colchetes, mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de realizar isto que seja mais simples e rápida.

Comment: Você não conseguiu com o for?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como ler dados de arquivos txt usando Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74972/28595)

Comment: @Douglas infelizmente não

Comment: O padrão tem que ser esse mesmo? Se não for procure usar XML ou JSON que já facilita. E nesse seu caso acredito que só com for mesmo, é o que basicamente os padrões de arquivos "tagiados" utilizam.

Comment: Inclusive em JSON existem ferramentas que já fazem conversão Java/String JSON e vice versa. [Exemplo](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

Comment: Obrigado a todos sou iniciante e ainda não conhecia JSON

Comment: Você poderia fazer um for e dentro dele um if, que impede que ele retorne todo o texto da linha. Uma dica, use o lenght com um array para destacar oq vc não quer, no caso "name:".

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia quem sabe utilizar expressão regular neste caso:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class testeajuda {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File diretorio = new File("C:\\testes\\"); //Diretório de entrada 
        File[] arquivos = diretorio.listFiles();

        if (arquivos != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arquivos.length; ++i) {
                if (arquivos[i].getName().endsWith("txt")) {
                    File f = arquivos[i];
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String linha = "";
                    String teste = "";
                    while ((linha = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(":\\s\\w*").matcher(linha); // Primeiro Filtro (Pega tudo que tem :, espaço, e tudo que vem depois que seja alfanumerico)
                        while (matcher.find()) {

                            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":\\s"); // Segundo Filtro (Elimina o ":" e o espaço)
                            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(matcher.group()).useDelimiter(pattern);
                            Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(teste);
                            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                                teste = scanner.next(); 
                                System.out.println(teste); // retorna apenas "Ricardo"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```