# Leitura de arquivo de texto

Tags: java, arquivo

Preciso lidar com um arquivo de 3 linhas com a seguinte estrutura:

```
nome
data
horário
```

Para fazer a leitura desse método eu uso os seguintes comandos:

```
BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader("dados/dados.txt"));
ArrayList<String> dados = new ArrayList<>();

String linha = "";

while((linha = leitor.readLine()) != null){
    dados.add(linha);
}

leitor.close();
```

Mas ao final da leitura, a primeira linha do arquivo fica corrompida com o valor `null`, quando na verdade era pra continuar com o valor do campo nome.

Como posso fazer para ler o arquivo sem corrompê-lo?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como ler dados de arquivos txt usando Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74972/como-ler-dados-de-arquivos-txt-usando-java?rq=1)

Comment: Fiz exatamente o que você fez e o resultado saiu perfeito. Não parece ser problema de código. Tentou fazer alguma alteração?

Comment: To achando que pode ser problema em um outro método que serve para verificar se o arquivo esta vazio ou não

Comment: nesse método eu uso File arquivo = new File("dados/dados.txt"); apenas

Comment: @Roney Se possível poste o código desse método.

Answer (score 1):

Verifica o encoding que você está usando. Os problemas que ocorrem com arquivos corrompidos costumam ser relacionados com o encoding utilizado para a leitura do arquivo. Olha o seguinte post e faz a mudança indicada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096844/how-to-read-a-file-in-java-with-specific-character-encoding.

Então no seu caso ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
String fileName = "dados/dados.txt";
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(isr);
ArrayList<String> dados = new ArrayList<>();

String linha = "";

while((linha = leitor.readLine()) != null){
  dados.add(linha);
}

leitor.close();
```

Troca o charset UTF8 se estiver utilizando outro encoding na tua aplicação.

Comment: Apesar do link ser do SOEn, é recomendado que você adicione um exemplo aqui, para que o link seja apenas para referencia e consulta.

Comment: Entendi. Vou colocar então! Obrigada ^^